# Как запретить просматривать общие изображения на сервере по прямой ссылке?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, apache

**Как запретить просматривать общие изображения на сервере** по прямой ссылке?

Все изображения находятся в папке `www/uploads/`. Для каждого пользователя выводится закреплённое за ним изображение. Но если какой-то пользователь создаст прямую ссылку на эту папку или файлы которые там хранятся, то он сможет получить доступ к другим изображениям.

**Какие есть варианты:**

1. Хранить изображения и все прочие загружаемые файлы пользователем, в БД. (не очень хороший вариант)
2. Запретить доступ к папке в которой хранятся изображения и прочие файлы, через файл файл конфигурации веб-сервера. Но в таком случае как пользователи смогут его увидеть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Принципиально решение выглядит таким образом:

1. В .htaccess делаете перенаправление всех запросов к изображениям на контролер.
2. Обработка запроса, определение прав на доступ к файлу и вывод изображение если такие права есть.

Минимальный набор .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

Rewritebase /

RewriteRule www/uploads/.*.png index.php?route=get_access
```

index.php:

```
// Проверка привелегий на доступ в файлу
if (!empty($_GET['route']) && $_GET['route'] == 'img_access') {
    header('Content-type:image/png');
    // В REQUEST_URI будет храниться реальный URI запроса,
    // к примеру /www/uploads/test.png
    include __DIR__ . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}
```

Это максимально упрощенный вариант, приведенный как демонстрация. Конечно же вам придется интегрировать скрипт проверки в свой движек/проект

В .htaccess все запросы из папки с картинками перенаправляются по index.php?route=get_access для того чтобы можно было подключать опеделенный контроллер.

Comment: Это уже близко к тому как нужно делать. Спасибо. `В .htaccess все запросы из папки с картинками перенаправляются по index.php?` - папка c картинками закрыта для доступа через  .htaccess.

Comment: А вас взломать не могут через эту строку кода - `include __DIR__ . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` ?

Comment: Сама по себе папка не закрыта, просто все запросы переадресовываются на index.php

Comment: Да, с точки зрения безопасности, код слаб. Его нужно дорабатывать. В htaccess сделать переадресацию запросов только для картинок, а в index.php проверять наличие файла, его расположение, тип

Answer (score 1):

Для .htaccess есть способ прямые ссылки на изображения. Нужно воспользоваться директивой `RewriteCond`.

При этом можно также запретить такие ссылки для тех или иных конкретных доменов  и даже указать заглушку для изображения или вернуть ошибку 403 (смотря, что Вам больше по душе).

Более подробно можно почитать [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/176299/).

Comment: Не могли бы вы привести пример, а то не понятно как там запретить просмотр изображений по прямой ссылке? Тут вопрос в том, как запретить доступ к изображению по прямой ссылке со стороны не хостинга а пользователя.